# Python matplotlib.pyplot: on_key is not triggered using canvas.mpl_connect

Tags: python, matplotlib, onkeydown

I'm trying to understand about why `on_key` is not triggered after running the following code. I know that after changing `V()` into `v = V()` or defining `on_key(self, event)` as a static method, `on_key` will be called correctly. But why not the following code work?

Thank you.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class V:
    def __init__(self):
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key)

    def on_key(self, event):
        print "user pressed =>", event.key

V()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Because `plt.show()` should be inside your `__init__` method.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan, Thank you for the reply. Putting `plt.show()` inside `__init__` does work. But accorinding to my understanding, `plt.show()` will create all the plots in the end. In this case, what is the difference?